# Linear Algebra Doubt regarding matrix of transformation wrt basis B and C

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $T$ be a linear transformation, T$:V\to W$, where $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over a field $F$.
Then the matrix of $T$ wrt the basis $B$ (of $V$) and $C$ (of $W$) is?

Is it $C^{-1}T(B)$?
This is the same as writing $[T(v_1),...,T(v_n)]$ where $B=(v_1,v_2,...,v_n)$ and $T(v_i)$ is written using the basis $C$ (ie coordinates when $C$ is the basis.
(I have written my answer below)

Comment: T: V ->W and basis of V be B and basis of W be C
the matrix of linear transformation wrt bases B and C is C^(-1) T(B) 
(where we write down C and B as the coefficients of some other common basis of W)

Answer (score 0):

Let T(v)=w

v=BX and w=CY

Let AX=Y
(such A exists, have A = [T(v1),...,T(vn)] where B=(v1,...,vn) and write T(vi) as coordinates when the basis C is used)

A is the matrix of transformation

T(BX)=CY;
T(BX) = T(B)X = CY = CAX for all X

Therefore T(B) = CA

Implies A = C^(-1)T(B)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).